# Rails - force field uppercase and validate uniquely

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, validation

Airports have four-letter ICAO codes. By convention, these are always uppercase. I'm creating a form for receiving user input, but this form needs to be able to accept user input in mixed case, and prevent them from creating dupes.

The default `:uniqueness` is case-sensitive, of course. I figured out how to transform the user's input to uppercase before it gets saved, but the problem is that this appears to be post-validation, instead of pre-validation.

For example, if there is already an Airport with ICAO of `KLAX`, a user can enter `klax`, it will get validated as unique, and then transformed to uppercase and stored, resulting in duplicates.

Here's my model code at present.

```
class Airport < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :icao, :name, :lat, :lon, :presence => true
  validates :icao, :uniqueness => true

  before_save :uppercase_icao

  def uppercase_icao
    icao.upcase!
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply fixed (as many problems with Rails are) - as Danny pointed out above, although not in his own answer so I can't accept it :), changing `before_save` to `before_validation` fixes it perfectly.

Answer (score 12):

Or a slightly different take:  Write a setter for `icao` that converts anything thrown at it to uppercase:

```
def icao=(val)
    self[:icao] = val.upcase
end
```

And then you can use regular uniqueness validation ([back it up with a unique index in your DB](http://railswarts.blogspot.com/2007/11/validatesuniquenessof-is-broken-and.html)).  Might even make things a little easier for the DB during finds, 'cause it doesn't have to worry about case-insensitive comparisons any more.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, interesting way of handling it as well. I also for some reason did not assume I would need to index my fields manually, so that's very good to know. Easily done, but important! Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

try this:

```
validates :icao, :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
```

Comment: or do a before_validation instead of before_save :)

Comment: Perfect, Danny - before_validation is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 5):

Updated answer for Rails 4.

```ruby
class Airport < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :icao, :name, :lat, :lon, :presence => true
  validates :icao, :uniqueness => { case_sensitive: false }

  def icao=(val)
    write_attribute :icao, val.upcase
  end
end
```